# Show that the function is a bijection.

Tags: functions, factorial

Let $A = \lbrace 1,2,6, 24, 120, .... \rbrace $. We define the following map $\alpha: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A, \; \alpha(a) = a!.$ I'm not able to show by the definition that this map is bijective.
I tried but it seems to be very simple, I could not visualize maybe a property. A little help would be very helpful

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What is the definition of the set $A$? The set notation with ellipsis isn't a formal definition.

Comment: A = {n! | n \in \mathbb{N}}

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by the obvious pattern that you're defining

$$A=\{n! : n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}.$$

So we're considering the mapping

$$\alpha : \mathbb{Z}^+\to A,\quad n\mapsto n!.$$

To show that $\alpha$ is bijective, we show that it's injective and surjective. Injectivity we can easily prove by noticing that

$$(n+1)!=n!\cdot\underbrace{(n+1)}_{>1}>n!$$

for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, from which it follows easily that if $n>m$, then

$$\alpha(n)>\alpha(m),$$

which proves injectivity. Now for surjectivity, if $a\in A$, then $a=n!$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ by definition, and so $a=\alpha(n)$, which proves surjectivity.

Comment: very grateful for the answer, I apologize for not defining the set A better. You managed to understand the surjectivity but not the injectivity :(

Comment: @DDR4 what problem do you have with the injectivity part?

Comment: @DDR4 that definition is equivalent to showing that if $a\neq b$, then $\alpha(a)\neq\alpha(b)$ (it's just the contrapositive), which is what I showed. Does that make sense?

Comment: @DDR4 don't worry about it :) if you think my answer answered your question then feel free to also accept it

Comment: as this is equivalent since we have an inequality? did not quite understand

Comment: If a is different from b, then the images will be (objective function definition). that's what i understand where it fits

Comment: @DDR4 having that $a\neq b$ is equivalent to having that $a>b$ or $b>a$ when $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$